# Reflection relating two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $S_1, S_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be two linear $k$-dimensional subspaces. Does there always exist a hyperplane $H$ such that $S_1 = R_H S_2$, where $R_H$ denotes the orthogonal reflection across $H$?

Geometric intuition leads me to suspect that this is obviously true, but a proof is eluding me.

**Edit:** As @zvbxrpl pointed out below, my intuition was wrong and the claim is false. However, the claim may still be true with "hyperplane" replaced by *some* linear subspace -- @zvbxrpl attempted to show this, but unfortunately there was an error in the proof.

Is the claim true if "hyperplane" is replaced by *some* linear subspace?

**Edit 2:** Studiosus has given an affirmative answer to the above revised question using Riemannian geometry. This is nice, but I am interested in a constructive, elementary answer using only linear algebra.

Comment: Intuitively, I would think that $H$ will always be the set of all points that are equidistant form $S_1$ and $S_2$

Comment: About codimension-1: if $P_1$ and $P_2$ are the projections onto the orthogonal complements of $S_1$ and $S_2$, then this locus would be a level set of the function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ given by
$$
f(x) = \|P_1x\|^2 - \|P_2 x\|^2
$$
so it clearly has codimension $1$.  As for why it's linear, I don't have a good justification.  But that's why I said "intuitively".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom sorry for my bad timing. if you see my edit above, I think I worked out the linear part as well. I like your explanation too.

Comment: your argument isn't quite correct; that's the wrong map, and anyway the kernel of that map generally has codimension $2$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hmm. I agree there is a problem with the codimension. It isn't clear to me what the right map would be.

Comment: I'm having the same problem; I don't think there's an obvious linear map whose kernel is what we want, unfortunately.  Maybe there's something nice we can say about how the orthogonal complements are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be an Euclidian vector space and $S_1,S_2$ two subspaces of same dimension $k$. Assume that $E = S_1 \oplus S_2$. Then there exists $f$ an orthogonal symetry such that $f(S_1)=S_2$ and $f(S_2)=S_1$.

> Proof: Let $P$ be the matrix of the scalar product on $E$, and choose a basis of $S_1$ and a basis of $S_2$ such that $P$ has the form :
>   $$ P = \begin{bmatrix} I_k & C \\ {}^tC & I_k \end{bmatrix}.$$
>   Let $A$ be a $k \times k$ invertible matrix and $f$ be an endomorphism of $E$ such that its matrix is :
>   $$ f = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & A^{-1} \\ A & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
>   Then $f$ is a symetry such that $f(S_1)=S_2$ and $f(S_2)=S_1$.
>   But $f$ is orthogonal iff
>   $${}^t f.P.f = P,$$
>   that is,
>   $$\begin{bmatrix} {}^tA.A & {}^tA.^tC.A^{-1} \\ {}^tA^{-1}.C.A & {}^tA^{-1}.A^{-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I_k & C \\ {}^tC & I_k \end{bmatrix}.$$
>   Which means that $A$ is orthogonal and $CA$ is symetric.
>   So if $A$ is the inverse of the orthognal part of $C$ in the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition), then $f$ is an orthogonal symetry.

In the general case, if $S_1$ and $S_2$ have an intersection. Denote $S = S_1 \cap S_2$, and write $S_1 = S \oplus^{\perp} T_1$ and $S_2 = S \oplus^{\perp} T_2$. Then $E = S \oplus^{\perp} (T_1 \oplus T_2)$. Now choose $f : E \rightarrow E$ such that $f$ switchs $T_1$ and $T_2$ on $T_1 \oplus T_2$ as above and such that $f$ is the identity on $S$.

Answer (score 2):

What you seek to prove is false if you require the subspace $H$ to be a hyperplane.

To see this, let $S_1,S_2$ two planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that only meet in the origin (e.g. $S_1=span\{e_1,e_2\},$ $S_2=span\{e_3,e_4\}$), then for every hyperplane $H\subseteq\mathbb{R}^4$ we have $L\subseteq H\cap S_2$ for some line $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$, which means that $L\subseteq R_HS_2$, so $R_HS_2\neq S_1$.

What is true is that for two equidimensional subspaces $S_1,S_2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ there is a subspace $T$ such that $R_TS_2=S_1$.

Let $\{u_1,\dots,u_h\}$ an orthonormal basis of $S_1\cap S_2$, $\{u_1,\dots,u_h,v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ an orthonormal basis of $S_1$, and $\{u_1,\dots,u_h,w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ an orthonormal basis of $S_2$. We put $T=span\{v_1+w_1,\dots,v_k+w_k\}$.

It is easy to see that $R_TS_2=S_1$. In fact we have $R_T(u_i)=-u_i$ since $T\perp(S_1\cap S_2)$ and $$R_T(w_i)=\Pi_T(w_i)-\Pi_{T^\perp}(w_i)=\frac{w_i+v_i}{2}-\frac{w_i-v_i}{2}=v_i$$ where $\Pi_T$ and $ \Pi_{T^\perp}$ are the orthogonal projections on $T$ and $T^\perp$, respectively. This concludes the proof. EDIT: This paragraph is wrong, see comments.

It's clear that the subspace $T$ is very much not unique. The presented choice for $T$  gives a subspace of minimal dimension with the desired property. If you are interested in a subspace of maximal dimension, a possible choice is $T'=T\oplus(S_1\cap S_2)\oplus(S_1+S_2)^\perp$

Comment: Why is it true that $\Pi_T(w_i)-\Pi_{T^\perp}(w_i)=\frac{w_i+v_i}{2}-\frac{w_i-v_i}{2}$? I'm not following this part.

Comment: it seems tricky to me because the basis you have chosen for $T$ is not orthonormal so the expression for orthogonal projection is more complicated. I'm really hoping that the big picture is right and we can find a subspaces $T$ with the property you claim.

Comment: You're right, the thing I've written doesn't work.
If we restrict to $S_1+S_2$ and quotient out $S_1\cap S_2$ we can reduce ourselves to two $k$-spaces in $\mathbb{R}^{2k}$ that span the whole space and you only need to find a reflection that sends one in the other.

Comment: Is it obvious that this can always be done for two $k$-spaces spanning $\mathbb{R}^{2k}$? And supposing it can, I'm not sure how this reflection can then be extended to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof of the claim made by zvbxrpl using Riemannian geometry; it is a bit over the top as there should be just a linear algebra argument, I just do not have to to work out an elementary proof:

**Theorem.** For every pair of $k$-dimensional linear subspaces $P, Q$ in $E^n$ there exists an isometric involution $s=s_R$ whose fixed point set is a $k$-dimensional subspace $R$ in $E^n$ such that $s(P)=Q, s(Q)=P$.

**Proof.** The space of $k$-dimensional linear subspaces in $E^n$ can be equipped with the structure of a smooth manifold, called the *Grassmannian* $Gr_k(E^n)$. The latter admits a Riemannian metric making it into a *symmetric space*: For every $P\in Gr_k(E^n)$ there exists an isometric involution $s_P$ fixing $P$ pointwise such that the derivative of $s_P$ at $P$ is $-1$. More specifically, $s_P$ is the unique isometric (with respect to the euclidean metric on $E^n$) linear involution of $E^n$ fixing $P$ pointwise and having $-1$-eigenspace equal to the orthogonal complement to $P$.

See for instance pages 1-5 of these [notes](http://myweb.rz.uni-augsburg.de/~eschenbu/symspace.pdf) by Eschenburg where he works out this in detail.

Now, given two elements $P, Q\in Gr_k(E^n)$, there is a (possibly nonunique) minimizing geodesic $c$ connecting $P$ to $Q$. Let $R$ be the midpoint of this geodesic. Then the involution $s_R$ will send $c$ to itself and reverse its orientation, thus sending $P$ to $Q$ and $Q$ to $P$. qed

Comment: How ironic. The reason I asked this question is because I was trying to prove something about the Grassmannian (trying to relate geodesics with a certain sequence of principal component analyses (PCA)). I am going to read those notes. Thank you. I would still enjoy reading a more elementary answer if anyone can produce one, though I do like your answer. Oh, and when you said "$c$", did you mean "$R$"?

Comment: Disregard my question about $R$ and $c$.